# Extract hex colors from image field for taxonomy vocabulary

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

For a project in D7. I need to extract all the colors from an image field. I am looking for a module or solution to save the colors (ie Taxonomy term). So I can search on them.

I have found a solution for D6: https://drupal.org/project/visual_search

Is there an alternative for D7?

Answer (score 0):

If your happy to use a custom module then something a simple as this would do the trick:

```
$colours = db_query("SELECT field_my_colour_field_value FROM field_data_field_my_colour_field")->fetchCol();
```